# Read names from .txt File and add it to a linked list

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

I want to create a linked list, which contains names from a input.txt File.
First name and last name are seperated by a blank space and after the last name there is a linebreak.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
   char* firstname;
   char* lastname;
   struct node *next;
   }node;

node *add(node *head, char* fnme, char* lnme){
   node *new_node;
   new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   if(new_node == NULL)
      printf("Fehler bei Speicher reservierung...");
   new_node->firstname = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
   if(new_node->firstname == NULL)
      printf("Fehler bei Speicher reservierung...");
   new_node->lastname = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
   if(new_node->lastname == NULL)
      printf("Fehler bei Speicher reservierung...");

   strcpy(new_node->firstname, fnme);
   strcpy(new_node->lastname, lnme);

   if(head == NULL){
      head = new_node;
      head->next = NULL;
      return head;
   }

   node *current;
   current = head;

   while(current->next != NULL){
      current = current->next;
   }

   current->next = new_node;
   new_node->next = NULL;
   return head;
 }

 void print(node *head){
   node *current;
   current = head;

   while(current != NULL){
     printf("%s %s\n", current->firstname, current->lastname);
     current = current->next;
    }
   }

int main(){

  node *head = NULL;

  char character;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  while ((character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  char *fnme, *lnme;
  fnme = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  if(fnme == NULL)
     printf("Fehler bei Speicher reservierung...");
  lnme = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  if(lnme == NULL)
     printf("Fehler bei Speicher reservierung...");

  int i = 0;
  while (character != ' ') {
     fnme[i++] = character;
     character = fgetc(fp);
  }
  fnme[++i] = '\0';   // NULL-terminate

  i = 0;
  while (character != '\n') {
     lnme[i++] = character;
     character = fgetc(fp);
  }
  lnme[++i] = '\0';  // NULL-terminate

  head = add(head, fnme, lnme);   

  free(fnme);
  free(lnme);
 }
 print(head);
 return 0;
}
```

I never worked with strcat, somehow that doesn't work. I also tried using char-arrays instead of pointers but its the same result.
Maybe I have to use other functions?

## Update 1:

Somehow the Output is strange, seems like it's never going in the if-block in the add() function.
Output with 2 names in the .txt-file:
pt? pt?
Peter Parker
Klark Kent

## Update 2:

Changed the Return type of the add() function, now it works

Comment: Because you have `head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` in your main() function, so head will never be NULL.  Also, you'd better check the return value of malloc, make sure the memory allocation succeed.

Comment: ok I deleted the ' head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); ' out of the main() but now I dont get any output ^^ and yea I will add the return check of malloc

Comment: Because you have other issues in the code. Anyway, I'll paste the full working solution here.

Comment: I fixed it, I will edit my post again

Comment: @colin thank you very much for youre help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code a little bit, and it should work. You can not use `strcat` in that way, since the second parameter of `strcat` accepts `const char *`, and you have `char`, so your code won't compile.

Also something noteworthy here is: I assume the function `add` will make a deepcopy for both `fnme` and `anme`, otherwise, you cannot simply free them here.

```
while ((character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    char *fnme, *anme;
    fnme = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    anme = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    int i = 0;
    while (character != ' ') {
        fnme[i++] = character;
        character = fgetc(fp);
    }
    fnme[++i] = '\0';   // NULL-terminate

    i = 0;
    while (character != '\n') {
        anme[i++] = character;
        character = fgetc(fp);
    }
    anme[++i] = '\0';  // NULL-terminate

    add(head, fnme, anme);   // Assume 'add' will make deep copy of both fname and 
                             // anme, otherwise you cannot free them here.
    free(fnme);
    free(anme);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I wanted!

Comment: Now I wrote the add() function but somehow it doesnt add a node at the beginning, I think i'm initalising the head wrong thats the output of my programm at the moment: pt? pt?, Peter Parker, Klark Kent (Example with 2 Names in the .txt File). I will Update my post above, maybe you find the mistake there too.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` is definitely not the right thing to use. As your compiler should be telling, you're firstly passing in the wrong type of variable in to it. It takes 2 strings and `character` is just a `char`.

Strings in C are NUL terminated and having just allocated memory for `anme` and `fnme`, neither of them will be initialised so won't contain that NUL termination, so you'll be experiencing undefined behaviour.

Instead, just treat them like an array and store the characters as you read them in and then remember to NUL terminate it when you've finished reading in all the characters.

```
int count = 0;

do{  
    fnme[count++] = character;
    character = fgetc(fp);
}while(character != ' ');
fnme[count]='\0'; // Need to NUL terminate the string

count = 0; // Remember to reset count to 0
do{  
    anme[count++] = character;
    character = fgetc(fp);
}while(character != '\n');
anme[count]='\0'; // Need to NUL terminate the string
```

This method also allows you to check that `count` doesn't exceed the size you've allocated, which in this case is 99 as the last space is needed for the NUL character.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in `add()` function. This is the full solution.
BTW, since this is a follow up question, you'd better ask it in a new post rather than updating the original one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
  char *forame;
  char *aftername;
  struct node *next;
}node;

void add(node **head, char* fnme, char* lnme){
  node *new_node;
  new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  new_node->forame = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  new_node->aftername = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(new_node->forame, fnme);
  strcpy(new_node->aftername, lnme);

  if (*head == NULL){
    *head = new_node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return;
  }

  node *current;
  current = *head;

  while(current->next != NULL){
     current = current->next;
  }

  current->next = new_node;
  new_node->next = NULL;
}

void print(node *head){
   node *current;
   current = head;

  while(current != NULL){
      printf("%s %s\n", current->forame, current->aftername);
      current = current->next;
  }
}

int main() {

  node *head = NULL;
  char character;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  while ((character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
      char *fnme, *lnme;
      fnme = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
      lnme = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

      int i = 0;
      while (character != ' ') {
          fnme[i++] = character;
          character = fgetc(fp);
      }
      fnme[++i] = '\0';

      i = 0;
      while (character != '\n') {
          lnme[i++] = character;
          character = fgetc(fp);
      }
      lnme[++i] = '\0';

      add(&head, fnme, lnme);

     free(fnme);
     free(lnme);
  }

  print(head);
  return 0;
}
```